# Is it possible to know if the audio device is powered on on PI3

Tags: raspbian, audio, hifiberry

I have a raspberry PI3 with a hifiberry hat that I use as a music server. It is plugged to a HiFi device (Denon amplifier). I would like to know if the amplifier is powered on or not, in order to close all raspberry connections.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the hat maker : no, it is not possible.